# Get filtered values from SQL Alchemy ORM Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a [Query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) object which I've done some filtering on. Now I pass that query around and then later I'd like to see what I've filtered on, using some kind of inspection.

I've got as far as:

```
>>> q = session.query(Activity).filter(Activity.label == "Foo")
>>> print(q.whereclause)
table.activity.label = :label_1
```

I can't find a way to get anything else out of that `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression` other than the column name (not the filtered value which I want, in this case "Foo").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `_criterion` attribute for more detailed info.
Examples:

```
In [1]: first = User.query.filter(User.confirmed_at.isnot(None))

In [2]: vars(first._criterion)
Out[2]: 
{'_orig': (Column('confirmed_at', DateTime(), table=<users>),
  <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x7f7a667e25c0>),
 'left': Column('confirmed_at', DateTime(), table=<users>),
 'modifiers': {},
 'negate': <function sqlalchemy.sql.operators.is_>,
 'operator': <function sqlalchemy.sql.operators.isnot>,
 'right': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x7f7a667e25c0>,
 'type': NullType()}

In [3]: second = User.query.filter(User.login_count > 5)

In [4]: vars(second._criterion)
Out[4]: 
{'_orig': (Column('login_count', Integer(), table=<users>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause('0', for_update=False)),
  BindParameter('%(140163529198168 login_count)s', 5, type_=Integer())),
 'left': Column('login_count', Integer(), table=<users>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause('0', for_update=False)),
 'modifiers': {},
 'negate': <function _operator.le>,
 'operator': <function _operator.gt>,
 'right': BindParameter('%(140163529198168 login_count)s', 5, type_=Integer()),
 'type': Boolean()}
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful. I didn't know about `vars`! `.whereclause` is just an alias for `._criterion`. So, in this case, I can use `q.whereclause.right.effective_value`. That gives me the "Foo" I was after. Thanks for showing me `vars` :)